# How to provide username and password within FTP URL for direct download in a browser?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, passwords, ftp, usability

Modern browsers like Chrome and Firefox can handle FTP downloads:

```
ftp://my-ftp.com/my-file.csv
```

I want to share a link to another person and I don't want them to enter a username and password through a prompt.

I am aware of the security impact, yet in this case ease of use has precedence. I wonder if there is an option to provide the credentials within the FTP URL directly.

Comment: This feature has been rolled back to abyss. Neither Chrome nor Edge support `ftp://` protocol in URL / omnibar anymore as of writing this (January 2023). Pasting such URL to omnibar and pressing `Enter` does nothing (no effect).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can provide the credentials to the URL like so:

```
username:password@host
```

Your example would become:

```
ftp://username:password@my-ftp.com/my-file.csv
```

---

You will run into problems if the user name contains invalid symbols such as `@`:

```
 ftp://usern@me:password@my-ftp.com/my-file.csv
```

For such a download, I had to fallback on using a client allowing the symbol, e.g. FileZilla.

Answer (score 1):

Notable exception (for HTTP and HTTPS protocols) is IE:

> Internet Explorer versions 3.0 to 6.0 support the following syntax for HTTP or HTTPS URLs:
>   `http(s)://username:password@server/resource.ext`
>   You can use this URL syntax to automatically send user information to a Web site that supports the basic authentication method.

([Source](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/834489/internet-explorer-does-not-support-user-names-and-passwords-in-web-sit)). They do not support it for security concerns:

> A malicious user might use this URL syntax to create a hyperlink that appears to open a legitimate Web site but actually opens a deceptive (spoofed) Web site. For example, the following URL appears to open http://www.wingtiptoys.com but actually opens http://example.com:
>   http://www.wingtiptoys.com@example.com

Comment: Does ie handle FTP at all?

Comment: ftp://ftp.freebsd.org/ seems to work (IE11).