# Provide a FTP credentials when opening remote database from command-line

Tags: passwords, ftp, keepass

**tl;dr;** *Can I provide **FTP login and password** (needed to fetch the database file from remote FTP server; **not** those needed to decrypt database itself) when launching KeePass in Windows 11? If so, how can I do this?*

---

This is a follow up to [my other question on using KeePass with FTP source](https://superuser.com/q/1761441/156554).

### Problem

I can run KeePass pointing it to a database file:

```
KeePass.exe "d:\my-KeePass-db.kdbx"
```

I can [provide password](https://keepass.info/help/base/cmdline.html) non-interactively:

```
KeePass.exe "C:\My Documents\MyDatabaseWithPw.kdbx" -pw:abc
```

Or key:

```
KeePass.exe "C:\Doooocs\DB\KP\My.kdbx" -keyfile:F:\pwsafe.key
```

Or both in the same time:

```
KeePass.exe "C:\Doooocs\DB\KP\My.kdbx" -pw:abc -keyfile:F:\pwsafe.key
```

I can point KeePass to [a remote database](https://superuser.com/q/1287857/156554) instead of local file:

```
KeePass.exe "ftp://keepass.info/db/example.kdbx"
```

But how can I provide FTP login and password in command line, in addition to database password or keyfile, to be able to open such database completely non-interactively?

### Analysis / Research

This seems to be not working at all (emphasis mine):

> KeePass.exe "ftp://**kurapr:kupa!123**@keepass.ddns.me/dbs/company/fiveosix/mwp.kdbx"

Because:

[image]

Is there any workaround to this?

Answer (score 1):

Following [KeePass guide](https://keepass.info/help/base/cmdline.html) and [this KeePass forum answer](https://sourceforge.net/p/keepass/discussion/329220/thread/9673208ab3/#dd62), you can use following switches:

```
-iousername:[username]
-iopassword:[password]
-ioiscomplete
```

So, the complete command-line (or Windows shortcut) string becomes something around this:

```
"C:\KeePass\KeePass.exe" ftp://some.ftp.server/db.kdbx -iousername:[username] -iopassword:[password] -ioiscomplete
```

Running KeePass the described way should open your FTP database right-away, without asking you to provide password (`-iopassword:[password]`) or login (`-iousername:[username]`) and even without showing the window that is presented in OP's image (`ioiscomplete`).

All you have to do is to provide master password (unless you have your database configured to use keyfile or system credentials).

Source: [here](https://keepass.info/help/base/cmdline.html) and [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/keepass/discussion/329220/thread/9673208ab3/#dd62).