# KeePass does not remember FTP login and password

Tags: ftp, credentials, keepass

Following my [other question on using KeePass with FTP source](https://superuser.com/q/1760938/156554), can someone explain me what am I *not understanding* in the following picture?

[image]

Either I am missing something or the feature of remembering FTP credentials does not work at all in the newest public version of KeePass (2.52).

[KeePass guide](https://keepass.info/help/v2/ioconnect.html) says that this feature should work as expected:

> KeePass can remember the FTP credentials, if you wish. You can choose between remembering everything (user name and password), partially (user name only) and not remembering the credentials at all.

Is this some kind of bug or I am doing something wrong?

<sub>BTW: Opening the database changes nothing; next time KeePass asks for FTP password and login again.</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question -- there is nothing that you do wrong. This is how these things work in KeePass 2.52. If you want your FTP credentials to be remembered, you must open it directly from KeePass, from recent list. Opening it as a command-line parameter does not work (i.e. credentials are not remembered).

These steps work for me:

1. Open KeePass
2. Click *File* → *Open* → *Open URL...*
3. Provide path and credentials, and set to remember
4. Provide master password for the opened .kbdx file (this is required so this FTP database is added to the recently-opened files list)
5. Verify that you can see the contents
6. Close KeePass

Now the credentials should be remembered on next launch, and KeePass should ask for the master password of your FTP vault only. There should be no asking about FTP credentials, as long as you're opening given database from recent list or from menu, not as command-line argument.

If you open some other vault, then you can return to the FTP vault with: *File* → *Open Recent* → [list]

---

If the above solution does not work and you are still asked for FTP credentials then check if the FTP credentials and path are getting saved correctly to the KeePass config file.

It is stored in:

```
C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Roaming\KeePass\KeePass.config.xml
```

An example content of the relevant part (`ConnectionInfo`) is:

```
<ConnectionInfo>
    <Path>ftp://server//path/Test-FTP-Database.kdbx</Path>
    <UserName>USERNAME</UserName>
    <Password>OBFuscATEd</Password>
    <CredProtMode>Obf</CredProtMode>
    <CredSaveMode>SaveCred</CredSaveMode>
</ConnectionInfo>
```

Also check that KeePass is able to update the config at all (make sure it's not in use or whatever). That is -- change something in your FTP connection and check, if that change is reflected in the config file.

Comment: I guess the KeePass documentation could be more clear about that.